# Vue.js - Passing :key of row to a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

This is my first time messing with data-tables in vue.js, so I pulled the teams.id from the api, and set it as the unique key for each row in the data-table. My problem is that I am having trouble passing the key to the 'delete' function. I am able to get the index but I am unable to find a way to get the key of said row.

```
<v-data-table
:headers="headers"
:items="teams"
:key="teams.id"
sort-by="id"
class="elevation-1"
>

<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
<v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
>
    fas fa-trash
</v-icon>
</template>
</v-data-table>

deleteItem(item) {
    const index = this.teams.indexOf(item)
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) {
        axios.delete(this.apiUrl+index).then(resp => {
            this.teams.splice(index, 1)
        })
    }
},
```

Thank you!

Comment: If `:key="teams.id"` then `item.id` would yield your key in the function, no?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, can't believe I spent hours on this. I really appreciate you helping me out as I am inexperienced with Vue.js. You are absolutely right. I would appreciate you leaving a comment so I can mark you as an answer for future users.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'd suggest reposting the solution as an answer so it can be accepted and more easily viewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `key` here references a property on the `item` its self, you can access that property from within the callback function given the slot props:

```js
deleteItem(item) {
  console.log(item.id) // property exists here
}
```